# can I use SLAM for a virtual robot?

Tags: ros, slam, ros-melodic, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm working on a project in which I have to use SLAM and navigation for the robot.
I want to know if it is possible to use SLAM for my virtual robot by moving in a Gazebo world , or is it mandatory to have the real robot (hardware) running around?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322820/can-i-use-slam-for-a-virtual-robot?/) by [Syrine](https://answers.ros.org/users/41424/syrine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can definitely use Gazebo or any other simulator (e.g. Stage).
The SLAM algorithm will be embedded into a node that requires streams of sensor data.

From the algorithm point of view there are no differences if these are coming from real sensors or "fake" ones from a simulator.

Here a tutorial with Gazebo and Gmapping SLAM algorithm
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-09**:
While this comment is in general true (ie: due to the decoupling afforded by ROS a SLAM node should not care about whether it receives input from "real" or "virtual" sensors), there is one thing I've observed when using SLAM in simulated environments: real world environments are messy and highly unstructured. SLAM algorithms typically like that (lots of features, high saliency). Simulated environments (ie: models) might be too clean for a particular algorithm to work.

This will not affect all algorithms in the same way, but it may be something to keep in mind.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-05-09**:
Yes, agree 100%.
If the user wants to test laser-based SLAM algorithm, an alternative to "clean models" consists in using as ground truth a map obtained from a different SLAM run, such as these ones [http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~stachnis/datasets.html](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Estachnis/datasets.html) or from the RADISH database https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/62236

**Comment by [Syrine](https://answers.ros.org/users/41424/syrine/) on 2019-05-09**:
Hi, thank you all that is definitely helpful.
And about gmapping on melodic, Since I'm a beginner I don't really know what it means to "build gmapping from source" as indicated in the following link https://answers.ros.org/question/296170/melodic-gmapping/
any help?? thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-09**:
It's poor practice to ask follow-up questions in comments under accepted answers, but see whether #q300480 helps.